# Array of class objects in android

Tags: java, android, arrays, class

I have constructed a class to mimic a C# struct:

```
public class Favourite {
    protected  String favName;
    protected  String favText;
    protected String favDelay;
    protected GeoPoint favPoint;
    protected Uri favUri;
}
```

I want to create an array of this class:

```
Favourite[] fav;
```

When I try to access this array:

```
fav[s].favName = bufr;
```

I get a NullPointerException.  `bufr` does contain data.  I have tracked it down to accessing the array as the following code:

```
fav[s].favName = "";
```

also produces  a NullPointerException.

I have searched high and low for some indication as to whether or not what I am doing is allowed but cannot find anything.

I suppose my questions are:

Are you allowed to create an array of a class object?
If so, how do you refer to that array?

I know I could do this using five separate arrays of the variables but I feel that putting them into a class gives a better structure and is more elegant (I like elegance).

Comment: Have you initialized fav[s] such that favName exists?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that `fav[s]` is null.

I don't know about C#, but in Java, you have to initialize the elements of the array individually; you can't just declare the array and get it automatically filled.

You're going to have to loop through `fav` and fill it with new `Favourite` objects.

Either assign `fav[s] = new Favourite()` the first time you use `fav[s]`, or initialize it all at once by doing

```
for (int i = 0; i < fav.length; i++) {
  fav[s] = new Favourite();
}
```

Comment: In C# if the OP had created a struct, it would be a value type, so the array would be full of "empty" values. That would be a bad idea for the given type, mind you - it doesn't feel like a natural value type. I will attempt to convert you to C# tomorrow ;)

Answer (score 3):

```
Favourite[] fav = new Favourite[23]; // Allocate an array of 23 items
```

Now you have 23 of them!

Answer (score 1):

You need to put items into the array.  The declared array simply has null in each slot; you need to do something like `fav[s] = new Favourite()`.